# PHP, XML & XPath: Display specific nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I'm struggling with a task. I'm trying to create a function which shows only Journal elements where Author1 / Auth1 is one of the authors. I do get the three Journal elements listed, but I'm only capable of separating each Journal to a new line. **I can't manage to separate each Journal-child in the result (and preferably with text nexto the value) to new lines  `(<br />)`.**

I have the following XML document:

```
<Journals>
    <Journal>
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author1</AuthorName> 
        <AuthorName>Author2</AuthorName> 
        <AuthorName>Author3</AuthorName>
        <JournalName>One</JournalName>
    </Journal>
    <Journal>
        <Title>Title2</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author2</AuthorName>
        <AuthorName>Author1</AuthorName>
        <JournalName>Two</JournalName>
    </Journal>
    <Journal>
        <Title>Title3</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author3</AuthorName>
        <JournalName>Three</JournalName>
    </Journal>
    <Journal>
        <Title>Title4</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author3</AuthorName> 
        <AuthorName>Author2</AuthorName> 
        <AuthorName>Author4</AuthorName>
        <JournalName>Four</JournalName>
    </Journal>
    <Journal>
        <Title>Title5</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author2</AuthorName> 
        <AuthorName>Auth1</AuthorName>
        <JournalName>Five</JournalName>
    </Journal>
    <Journal>
        <Title>Title6</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author2</AuthorName> 
        <AuthorName>Author3</AuthorName>
        <JournalName>Six</JournalName>
    </Journal>
</Journals>
```

And the following PHP document:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);


/* FUNCTION FOR ALL ARTICLES PUBLISHED BY Author1 */
  function taskOne()              
    {   
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load("file.xml"); 
    $xml = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = $xml->evaluate("/Journals/Journal/AuthorName[contains(. , 'Author1') or contains(. , 'Auth1')]/..");
    foreach ($query as $temp)
      {
      echo $temp->nodeValue . "<br />";
      }
    }
    taskOne();
?>
```

Now another question: How come using the XPath query: `/Journals/Journal[contains(AuthorName, 'Author1') or contains(AuthorName, 'Auth1')]`only lists the Journal where Author1 is the top author, and not those where he's child-sibling number two or three? 
**Here's the final output with XPath query:** `/Journals/Journal/AuthorName[contains(. , 'Author1') or contains(. , 'Auth1')]/..`

```
Title1 Author1 Author2 Author3 One 
Title2 Author2 Author1 Two 
Title5 Author2 Auth1 Five
```

**Here's the final output with XPath query:** `/Journals/Journal[contains(AuthorName, 'Author1') or contains(AuthorName, 'Auth1')]`

```
Title1 Author1 Author2 Author3 One
```

And for clarfications, this is want I'm trying to achieve:

```
Title: Title1 
Journal author: Author1 
Journal author: Author2 
Journal author: Author3 
Journal name:   One

Title: Title2
Journal author: Author2 
Journal author: Author1 
Journal name:   Two 

Title: Title5 
Journal author: Author2 
Journal author: Auth1 
Journal name:   Five
```

Comment: so whats the final output would look like?

Comment: @Ghost I added the output for both queries.

Comment: wait i mean in the first comment is, what should be the correct final output (the desired result).

Comment: @Ghost Added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just target that `<Journal>` which has children `<AuthorName>` that contains that needle that you want. You're already close:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$query = "//Journal[AuthorName[contains(., 'Author1') or contains(., 'Auth1')]]";

$journals = $xpath->query($query);
if($journals->length > 0) {
    foreach($journals as $journal) { // for each of the journal found
        foreach($journal->childNodes as $e) { // loop all its nodes/children
            if(isset($e->tagName)) {
                echo "$e->tagName: " . $e->nodeValue . '<br/>';
            }
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jVW1R0)

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow. Right now my brain is malfunctioning and needs sleep. Thanks for the reply! :-)

Comment: @Thomas sure man no prob, by the way i setup a demo for the output to fiddle around.

Comment: Sweet. Will check that out as well.